# If a medical provider refers a patient to another medical provider/business, do they have to disclose any financial interest they may have?

Tags: united-states, california, health, massachusetts

If a medical provider refers a patient to another medical provider or medical business (e.g., an imaging lab), do they have to disclose to the patient any financial interest they may have in the referral?

I am mostly interested in the following locations in the United States:

- California, United States
- Massachusetts, United States

Comment: Take a look at the Stark Law, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_Law.

Comment: @B540Glenn Thanks very much for the information, you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer as it seems to perfectly answer the question.